# CortexA15 coprocessor15 c15 register cannot be written

Tags: kernel, arm

When I write a value to the cp15 c15 reg, it does not take effect, even though I wrote to it from a kernel module.

```
kernel: 3.10.2
platform: arndale board
operating system: linaro ubuntu 13.07
```

Could someone give me a hand?

Comment: And i wrote it from kernel module.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  With the information currently available in the question, it is doubtful whether anyone can help you. It appears you have a kernel module that writes to (or tries to write to) the coprocessor register, but this doesn't work.  However, unless we can see how you are writing to that register — the code you're using — and preferably some other code that successfully writes to cp14 c15 register and cp15 c14 register (for example), it may not be obvious what the issue is (and it still may be mysterious with that information). Good luck!